# Specifying java version usage for Minecraft Server with flag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

**Problem**

I want to run two servers, one in 1.17 using Java 16 and the other in 1.12.2 using Java 8.

The argument I want to use in the .bat file is `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib" -jar` but it doesn't work.

**.bat**

The full .bat is as such.

```
@ECHO OFF
java -Xms10G -Xmx10G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch  -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=8 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=true -Daikars.new.flags=true "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe" -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2855.jar --nogui
pause
```

**Error message**

The error given is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe
```

I don't know how to resolve the error of the java class not being found.

**Additional details**

I am running [JRE 16](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html) and [Java 8](https://www.java.com/en/download/) on the same computer. Only the 1.17 servers start with this installation set up.

The 1.12.2 server starts when I uninstall JRE 16.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct binaries.

Suppose Java 15 is in your `PATH` variable. Then executing the plain `java` command will execute with the Java 15 binary.

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe` is your java 8 binary.

Thus, to execute forge on Java 8, you don't want to execute the plain `java` command, since that is java 15. You will need to qualify the whole path to your Java 8 executable, with the command:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe -jar <path to forge jar>`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the miscommunication. The bat file does have the path to forge jar. I've included the full bat file in the post. Thanks!

Comment: @Laythe The command you have written makes no sense at all. You execute `java <some arguments > "java.exe" -jar <forge dll> `. That is not how the `java` command works, it doesn't take *another* java executable as parameter.

Comment: Wait what? It doesn't take 2 java executables as parameters? I tried shifting the 1.8 java.exe into the server folder and ran java -Xms8G -Xmx8G -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2855.jar --nogui`. It worked. It used the 1.8 java.exe over the 1.16 java.exe.

Comment: @Lahyte If you type in `java` in the shell (or a script), what happen is that Windows needs to find an executable named Java. The *first* place Windows looks at is the current folder, then Windows checks the PATH. If you copy the `java.exe` of 1.8 into the server folder, and then execute the script **in that folder**, Windows will first find the 1.8 executable and not look further. In technical terms, that executable will shadow your 16 executable in your path. Crucially, this depends on the *working directory* in which you execute the script being the one with your java 1.8 exec.

Answer (score 0):

**Potential answer**

**Context**

I've installed 2 versions of java, 8 and 16. When I type `java -version` in command prompt, java 16 shows up.

The following is my .bat file for forge 1.12.2

```
@ECHO OFF
java -Xms10G -Xmx10G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch  -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=8 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=true -Daikars.new.flags=true -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2855.jar --nogui
pause
```

When trying to run a 1.12.2 forger server in this state, the following error message appears.

```
A problem occurred running the Server launcher.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:70)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
        ... 6 more
```

**Solution?**

I take the java.exe from where I've installed Java 8: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin`.

I put it inside my minecraft folder, in the same file level as the forge jar and bat file.

I use the same .bat as shown above, no modifications.

I run it, and the server turns on.

Comment: This is not the way to do it. I'm not certain what will happen but the executable may not know where to look for its supporting libraries if you've moved it.  Just take the path you've entered to the java exe and replace the one at the front with that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the word java at the beginning with `"<path\java.exe>"`,
if you leave the word java at the beginning it will choose a java automatically.

The correct format would look like this:

```
"<path\java.exe>" <some arguments> -jar <forge jar>
```

Don't forget ""

I had the same problem and looking at the posts here I could understand what was happening, I know this has already been answered, but I wanted to leave the answer in a more didactic way for the next ones who come looking.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
@ECHO OFF
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe" -Xms10G -Xmx10G  
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch  
-XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 
-XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=8 
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 
-XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=true 
-Daikars.new.flags=true -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2855.jar --nogui
pause
```